# Using Perl to Extract script type html/text

Tags: javascript, html, perl

I am currently trying to extract the page that a  script type="text/html" points to. For example [this CNN link](http://www.cnn.com/video/#/video/bestoftv/2012/04/24/nr-brooke-student-loans.cnn) has the line in the source:

```
<script type="text/html" id="pageTemplate"></script>
```

I want to download the contents of pageTemplate and be able to parse the results. I have been trying to use HTML::TagParser and I am able to get the element pageTemplate, but I can not get its contents.

Comment: It's probably using [icanhaz.js](http://icanhazjs.com/) or something similar, so the script is read and interpreted by some templating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is, "pageTemplate" doesn't have any contents.  Presumably, that's because it's going to be used as a stash for some html; scripts of type "text/html" don't actually *do* anything.  Ie, a `<script>` like this is an undisplayed DOM element that could be put to whatever purposes.

One possibility: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

Look thru the javascript associated with the CNN page for clues about what that id is being used for.

Comment: Use FireBug and inspecting the title ("Student Loan...") above the video, I am able to determine what I believe that id is being used for. My question is how I can access this information if I had the URL.

Comment: You could use LWP::UserAgent or WWW::Mechanize; you may have to figure out the exact nature of the request first, eg, by watching the page load with "Net" enabled in firebug.  There may be cookies involved, etc.